# Is there any chance of not creating SQL database under the SQL elastic pool in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am creating the SQL database in Azure programatically under the SQL elastic pool, but sometimes the database is not created under the SQL elastic pool, instead it is created outside of the SQL elastic pool with higher pricing tier.

Please let know if any one has any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: As you are doing this  programmatically it would be worth sharing the code snippet and which API you are using e.g. BICEP, Terraform etc

Comment: is this [Document](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/ms_sql.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/statements/alter-database-transact-sql.html) help you?

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't understand what's happening...